# Why wont wifi work on openbsd

Tags: wifi, openbsd, bsd

I'm on latest OpenBSD, fully installed, installed drivers for `iwx0` which is the wireless card I have. My `/etc/hostname.iwx0` has the following in it

```
nwid "mywifiname" wpakey "mypassphrase"
dhcp
```

And that's it. Every time I reboot i get

```
iwx0:...........no link
Iwx0:..........got link
Iwx0:..........no lease
```

I've read the man pages on `iwx0` and such but could not find a answer. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have access restrictions in place on your router? It's often possible to limit access to a DHCP server by MAC address, and you (or your admin) may have enabled this in the past, possibly.

Answer (score 0):

`tcpdump` will show you why, run `tcpdump -i iwx0 -y IEEE802_11_RADIO -v` for wireless frames.